# How to enable continuous (re)cycling R leaflet overlayGroup states without viewer intervention except to start and stop?

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

In the following code, I would like to have a control button to initiate and stop the following events:

1. turns all overlayGroups off,
2. then turns the 1st overlayGroup on for 1 second
3. then turns all overlayGroups off    for 1 second
4. then turns the 2nd overlayGroup on for 1 second
5. cycles until stopped.

```
library(leaflet)
icon.Union <- makeAwesomeIcon(icon = "chevron-down", 
         markerColor = "lightblue",
         iconColor="#FFFF33",
         library = "fa")
icon.Confederacy <- makeAwesomeIcon(icon = "chevron-down", 
         markerColor = "lightgray",
         iconColor="#FFFFFF",
         library = "fa")
lng = -98.5795;lat = 39.8283
leaflet() %>% 
            addTiles(group = "OSM") %>%
            setView(lng,lat, zoom = 4.0) %>%
addAwesomeMarkers(
                 lng = -77.23667, lat = 39.80861,
            label = "Gettysburg, PA",
            group = "Union",
            icon = icon.Union) %>%
addAwesomeMarkers(
         lng = -88.32183, lat = 35.15068,
            label = "Shiloh, TN",
         group = "Union",
            icon = icon.Union) %>%
addAwesomeMarkers(
            lng = -79.8747, lat = 32.7523,
            label = "Fort Sumter",
            group = "Confederacy",
            icon = icon.Confederacy) %>%       
addLayersControl(baseGroups="OSM",
         overlayGroups = c("Union", "Confederacy"),
            options= layersControlOptions(collapsed=TRUE))
```

I want to avoid requiring repetitive clicking on radio buttons to accomplish this.
Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.